# Can RCloud be reskinned using custom css?

Tags: rcloud

I'm new to RCloud. I've never used it, but a client wants to use it. Is it possible to easily reskin it so that it uses style guide (css) from the client?

Comment: You can style your notebooks by adding an asset named `rcloud-*.css` and it will load whenever the notebook is loaded in edit or view mode. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thanks @Gordon I'll give it a try